# ¿como puedo corregir este código para que tome un numero hexadecimal (string) y lo divida en la parte entera y decimal en python?

Tags: python, string

La idea es poder ejecutar este código en una consola de python, por eso uso la libreria `msvcrt`.
Desconozco si hay otra forma de hacerlo, pero lo que me interesa es poder trabajar con números hexadecimales, los cuales pueden contener letras.

```
import msvcrt
entrada=""
val= 1
entero=""
decimal=""

def separar(x):
    i = 0
    global val
    global entero
    global decimal
    while i < len(x):

        if x[i] == "," or x[i] == ".":
            val = 3
        elif  val < 2:
            entero = entero + x[i]
        elif val > 2:
            decimal = decimal + x[i]
        else:   
            pass
    i += 1

entrada = input("ingrese un valor en dec :")
print(entrada)
separar(entrada)
print("la parte entera es = ")
print(entero)
print("la parte decimal es = ,")
print(decimal)

msvcrt.getch()
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: y `entero, decimal = entrada.split(".")` no hace lo que quieres? Aunque lo que obtienes así (igual que con tu función, salvo que el último `i+=1` debería estar dentro del bucle) son dos cadenas, sean hexadecimales o no. No sé qué quieres hacer luego con ellas. De cualquier forma, no deberías usar varaibles globales. Puedes hacer que tu función retorne una tupla con las dos partes.

Comment: la función `.split(".")` funciona a la perfección para lo que quiero, desconocía su existencia (soy nuevo en python).